# Knockout JS Script works in Chrome but not in IE9

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a web page that works great in Chrome but not in IE9. The error that comes on the console from this error is

SCRIPT5022: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: [object Error];
Bindings value: foreach: statlist.

HTML is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="statsarea" data-bind="foreach: statlist">
           <p> TypeCount: <strong data-bind="text: TypeCount"></strong>, Priority: <strong data-bind="text: SentDate"></strong>
            <br/>
           </p>

    </div>


        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="models/messagecount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function MessageCountDataModel() {

    var self = this;
    var allCounts = (function() {

        var json = null;

        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json",
            'datatype': "json",
            'success': function(data) {
                self.statlist = data;
            }
        });
    })();
}

ko.applyBindings(new MessageCountDataModel());
```

One more piece of info is that that the json that comes out of the API looks something like this. I'm not sure if it's because the TypeCount is not a string?

```
[
    {
        "TypeCount": 102,
        "SentDate": "2014-08-18T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Why are you setting `allCounts` to the result of calling a function that never returns anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to use `async: false`. Maybe this is the problem because you don't initialize `statlist` as attribute in yout ViewModel. Better solution will be to make `statlist` to be an observable array, then make a async call and when it is ready to set the data.

Example:

```
function MessageCountDataModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.statlist = ko.observableArray();

    self.loadData = function() {
        $.ajax({
            'url': "http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json",
            'datatype': "json",
            'success': function(data) {
                self.statlist(data);
            }
        });
    };

    self.loadData();
}

ko.applyBindings(new MessageCountDataModel());
```

Comment: I like this but it's still not working in IE.9. Now I don't even see any HTML being produced. Chrome still works great.

Comment: I just check Firefox it's working in firefox as well. It's just IE9 that it's not working not sure why...

Comment: Is it possible to give a link with reproducible error under IE9 and working under other browsers?

Comment: I think I may have come up with the issue. My test web server is running on port 3000 and the REST API is on the same machine on a different part. I believe this has something to do with Cross Origin within IE, I just need to know how to fix it now :)

Comment: I'm wondering if you use two different ports for the API and the client how it is working on Chrome and FF. You need to use the same port, or maybe you need to convert your responses to JSONP instead of JSON.